# Missing preferences on Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2017

My preferences page in Visual Studio is missing. It is meant to be under file but it just isn't there.

I have been trying to change my code theme but ran into the issue of not being able to find the preference page. I have the latest version of Visual Studio. Is there any ways to get preferences back or an other way to change the code theme for Visual Studio?

Comment: If you had researched this, you should've turned up the answer mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179201/cannot-find-property-manager-option-in-visual-studio-not-express-version . Read the answer starting "Try resetting your View menu" and upvote it if it resolves your issue.

Comment: I have already tried that and it fixed nothing.

Comment: OK.  The things you have tried already should generally be reflected in your question, so that people answering don't suggest the same things you've already done that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio Code version 1.80.1 on Mac the preferences tab can be found under the Code icon at the top left of the screen(should be on the left of your File icon). From here you can navigate to preferences.

Comment: Hello, I don't think this solves the missing page problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using Visual Studio Code version 1.30.2 as an example, I see that you can also set the Color Theme by using `Ctrl+K Ctrl+T`. Or you can use `Ctrl+Shift+P` to open an interface where you can get to any command. Maybe these also work in Visual Studio 2017.

I see that Visual Studio 2017 has color themes under Tools > Options > Environment > General.

And under Tools > Customize, you might be able to get your File > Preferences menu item back.